# Informative "if" statement in "for" loop

Tags: c

Normally when I have a big for loop I put messages to inform me in which part of the process my program is, for example:

```c
for(i = 0; i < large_n; i++) {
    if( i % (large_n)/1000 == 0) {
       printf("We are at %ld \n", i);
    }
    // Do some other stuff
}
```

I was wondering if this hurts too much the performance (a priori) and if it is the case if there is a smarter alternative.Thanks in advance.

Comment: anyway at the end you remove it no ?

Comment: Why do you do `/1000`? I'd say that `i % large_n` should suffice for this.

Comment: Why do you care about performance for something you're only using in debug and development builds?

Comment: always `i % large_n == i`

Comment: Guys, the loop goes to `large_n`. The condition in the `if` should be `i % a_value_smaller_than_n == 0`, possibly `large_n / 1000`.

Comment: @NikosC. Because it takes long time (~ half a day). Any hour saved would be nice.

Comment: If the loop takes long enough to run that having this output is useful, then it will not have a significant impact on performance.  If the code runs so quickly that this output is not necessary, then the impact on total processing time may be substantial (this is not likely) but the total processing time is negligible, so having the output is merely annoying.

Comment: You might want to use `\r` instead of `\n`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell What is the difference between \r and \n?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Or rather why is preferable \r?

Comment: @Bunder, try it.  Instead of getting a newline for each printf, the new line will overwrite the previous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can split the large loop in order to check the condition sometimes only, but I don't know if this will really save time, that depends more on your "other stuff".

```
int T = ...; // times to check the condition, make sure large_n % T == 0
for(int t = 0; t < T; ++t)
{
  for(int i = large_n/T * t; i < large_n/T * (t+1); ++i)
  {
    // other stuff
  }
  printf("We are at %ld \n", large_n/T * (t+1));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of what is in your loop, I wouldn't be leaving statements like `printf` in unless it's essential to the application/user, nor would I use what are effectively redundant `if` statements, for the same reason.

Both of these are examples of trace level debugging. They're totally valid and in some cases very useful, but generally not ultimately so in the end application. In this respect, a usual thing to do is to only include them in the build when you actually want to use the information they provide. In this case, you might do something like this:

```
#define DEBUG

for(i = 0; i < large_n; i++) 
{
    #ifdef DEBUG
        if( i % (large_n)/1000 == 0) 
        {
            printf("We are at %ld \n", i);
        }
    #endif
}
```

Regarding the performance cost of including these debug outputs all the time, it will totally depend on the system you're running, the efficiency of whatever "printing" statement you're using to output the data, the check/s you're performing and, of course, how often you're trying to perform output.

Comment: +1 for the DEBUG mention, OP would probably find it useful that it can be defined with the `-DDEBUG=1` compiler flag, greatly aides debugging.

Answer (score 3):

Your mod test probably doesn't hurt performance but if you want a very quick test and you're prepared for multiples of two then consider a mathematical `and` test:

```
if ( ( i & 0xFF ) == 0 ) {
    /* this gets printed every 256 iterations */
    ...
}
```

or

```
if ( ( i & 0xFFFF ) == 0 ) {
    /* this gets printed every 65536 iterations */
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's the printf that uses up CPU, not the if

Comment: @LtWorf not always. If you are coding a very tight loop that performs some simple arithmetic and is spinning incredibly quickly then the percentage of time spent in the `if` statement matters. Sure, it is a rare case, but when it matters some bit-bashing can help. While a printf() does take a lot of time it becomes negligible if called sparingly in the loop - hence the purpose of the `if` call in the first place to only print on occasion. So while your assertion is usually correct it would be a mistake to make a blanket call without knowledge of what the loop contains.

Answer (score 0):

By placing a print statement inside of the for loop, you are sacrificing some performance.

Because the program needs to do a system call to write output to the screen every time the message is printed, it takes CPU time away from the program itself.

You can see the difference in performance between these two loops:

```
int i;
printf("Start Loop A\n");
for(i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    printf("%d ", i);
}
printf("Done with Loop A\n");

printf("Start Loop B\n");
for(i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    // Do Nothing
}
printf("Done with Loop B\n");
```

I would include timing code, but I am in the middle of work and can update it later over lunch.

If the difference isn't noticeable, you can increase 100000 to a larger number (although too large a number would cause the first loop to take WAY too long to complete).

Whoops, forgot to finish my answer.

To cut down on the number of system calls your program needs to make, you could check a condition first, and only print if that condition is true.

For example, if you were counting up as in my example code, you could only print out every 100th number by using `%`:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    if(i%100 == 0)
        printf("%d", i);
}
```

That will reduce the number of syscalls from ~100000 to ~1000, which in turn would increase the performance of the loop.

Comment: That's pretty much what I do. The question is rather that the "if" statement hurts the performance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is IO operation `printf` takes a much time than processor calculates. you can reduce the time if you can add them all and print finally.

Answer (score 0):

Notation:

```
Tp = total time spent executing the progress statements.
Tn = total time spent doing the other normal stuff.
>> = Much greater than
```

If performance is your main criteria, you want Tn >> Tp.  This strongly suggests that the code should be profiled so that you can pick appropriate values.  The routine 'printf()' is considered a slow routine (much slower than %) and is a blocking routine (that is, the thread that calls it may pend waiting for a resource used by it).

Personally, I like to abstract away the progress indicator.  It can be a logging mechanism,
a printf, a progress box, ....  Heck, it may be updating a structure that is read by another thread/task/process.

```
id = progressRegister (<some predefined type of progress update mechanism>);
for(i = 0; i < large_n; i++) {
    progressUpdate (id, <string>, i, large_n);
    // Do some other stuff
}
progressUnregister(id);
```

Yes, there is some overhead in calling the routine 'progressUpdate()' on each iteration, but again, as long as Tn >> Tp, it usually is not that important.

Hope this helps.